# Why does every string contain the empty string?

Tags: python, string

"ABCDE" has no empty character. But when I type

```
"" in "ABCDE"
```

Python interpreter returns `True`.

Why?

is there any empty character in "ABCDE"? I don't think so.

And I also found when I use these code:

```
target = ''
src = 'ABCDE'
src.find(target)
```

it returns 0 instead of -1

Why is this?

Comment: What do you mean by "an empty character"? How many characters do you think the string `""` contains?

Comment: `''` is even `in ''`… What are you actually trying to test? Whether your string contains a space? Or is longer than 0 characters?

Comment: @Chris There must be no "" in string "ABCDE"

Comment: @deceze That's not important, I just feel curious why the result is not -1

Comment: @BingSun, what do you mean by that? Try `len('')` and see if that helps to explain what's happening here.

Comment: because `'ABCDE'` can be represented as `'' + 'ABCDE'`, than first occurence of empty string is zero position

Comment: *"No `''` in `'...'`"* makes no sense, neither to us nor to Python. Explain it differently.

Comment: @Christ find() returns the very first target character position in string src and if the value is iterable, in returns whether list/turple/string src contains target. '' is an empty string/character and "ABCDE" have no empty string/character so the in result should return False and find function should return a -1 result.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov so if I use src.find(target,2) it returns 2 for "ABCDE " can be represented as 'AB'+''+'CDE'?

Comment: @BingSun, an "empty string" makes sense. An "empty _character_" is meaningless. In fact the empty string _is_ a substring (in fact, is _many_ substrings) of any string. Try `'foo'[0:0]`, `'foo'[1:0]`, etc. The empty string _can in fact_ be found in the string `'ABCDE'`. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) is quite clear about this as well.

Comment: I would classify this as *undefined operation*. If you're trying to ask *"can `''` fit into the string `x`"*, then the answer is *yes*, since you can insert `''` at any point in any string without changing it, so you can arguably *find* it in any string, so any string *contains* a `''`. You could argue the exact opposite as well. There is no way to *represent* `''` inside a string. A string can *be* `''`, a string cannot *contain* `''`. Bottom line: `'' in '...'` simply makes no real sense and there's no particular correct answer I'd expect out of it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143224/discussion-on-question-by-bing-sun-python-why-in-abcde-returns-true).

Answer (score 8):

For people with background in languages where string objects represented as arrays of characters it may be surprising, but if we try to follow such approach like

```
string = 'ABCDE'
characters_list = list(string)
```

then

```
'' in characters_list
```

will be `False` statement.

Empty string probably came from [mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string), where it is a neutral element for binary operation of [string concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation), i. e. for every string `a`

```
a + empty_string == empty_string + a == a
```

where `+` is a string concatenation symbol. Then "*substringing*" can be defined as follows:

- for every strings `a`, `b` we say `a` *is substring of* `b` iff exists strings `c`, `d` such that

  ```
  b == c + a + d
  ```

Let's denote `a` *is substring of* `b` as `a in b`.

With these definitions of *empty string* and *substringing* relation can be proved lemma

- `empty_string` is a substring of any string `a`:

  ```
  a == (definition of empty_string) == empty_string + a == 
  == (definition of empty_string) == empty_string + empty_string + a
  ```

  then if we define `c = empty_string` and `d = a`:

  ```
  a == c + empty_string + d
  ```

  and by definition `empty_string in a`.

Comment: Awesome! I loved it that you didn't just end with the differences in representation (array of characters). Instead you did a discrete math proof. Thanks and I think we should learn to answer in this manner more often.