# Python: Difference between "" and " " when creating a new variable with a empty string?? ( new_variable = " " )

Tags: python, string, quotations, isin

Oke, i've looked into [How to check if the string is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty) but it didn't help me. Also chat GPT talks weird if you dig into this question, and the python manual didnt help me either.

Language = python 3.11.1

```
previous_char = " "
vowels = 'aeiou'
print(previous_char in vowels)
```

this code evaluates as 'false' and length 1

But if you remove the space between the quotation marks in previous_char

```
previous_char = ""
vowels = 'aeiou'
print(previous_char in vowels)
```

this code evaluates as 'true' and length 0

So basically if you ask: is 'nothing' in vowels.. its true??
I don't find this logical, but on the other hand, if it would evaluate to false, it would also be weird.

I started coding 2 weeks ago for fun, i'm 35 years old, so please don't burn me to hard if this is some kind of dumb question.

But i'm a bit stuck in understanding why this is the way it is?

Comment: One is a space, the other is empry string. `if myString == "":` is VERY clear in the link you shared

Comment: Try `'aeiou'.count('')`, and you'll get 6. Python seems to treat the gaps between characters and outersides of the string as `''`.

Comment: It's a more useful property when using "advanced" tools like regular expressions, when an empty string may represent a pattern that is matched zero times.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603885/why-is-true-returned-when-checking-if-an-empty-string-is-in-another) answer your question?

Comment: ah, that seems to be something.. i tried the len() method before, then it gives 5, but with your proposed count('') method it gives 6 indeed.. still weird to me, butt it explains the behavior of the boolean check.

Comment: Other possible duplicates - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5206466/5320906) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43729159/5320906)

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for the links! very useful. I spent already 2 hours on experimenting with this problem myself, but i guess that's what learning/understanding is. If you go to the answer to soon or easy you'll learn nothing  ;-)

Comment: If they answer your question we can mark it as a duplicate of them - would that be ok?  The idea of Stack Overflow is to try to keep answers to questions in a single place as much as possible.

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes no problem with me, they answer the question in more details then I understand at the moment :-)  I didn't find those threads because i'm unfamiliar with more complex programming terminology but i learned a lot the past 2 weeks.

Comment: With time and study will come deeper understanding.

Answer (score 0):

`" "` is a string containing a single character (a space).

`""` is the empty string.

Comment: thanks, for the reply, thats what i also found out. But i still don't get why the check if the 'empty string' is IN 'aeiou' is true? and the check if the 'space' is in 'aeiou' false?

Comment: Well, the second case should be obvious - there's no space character in the string `"aeiou"`, so you get a `False`. The first case can be seen like this: any string can be written as another string that is the concatenation of itself and the empty string (in your case `"aeiou" + ""` is still the string `"aeiou". Therefore, the empty string can be said to be part of a non-empty string.

Comment: Not just a non-empty string, `'' in ''` is also `True`.

Comment: To be clear on the above, you can put the empty string _anywhere_ and it doesn't change the original string: `"aei" + "" + "ou"` still gives you the string `"aeiou"`. Basically, the empty string is like the string equivalent of the number 0 - adding or subtracting 0 to any number leaves it unchanged.